# Missing required prop error in Vue unit test

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-test-utils

I have a component with two required props. The unit test is failing because I get the following errors:

```
  console.error node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.js:589
    [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "heading"

    (found in <Root>)

  console.error node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.js:589
    [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "subHeading"

    (found in <Root>)

  console.error node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.js:589
    [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "heading"

    (found in <Root>)

  console.error node_modules\vue\dist\vue.runtime.common.js:589
    [Vue warn]: Missing required prop: "subHeading"
```

Component source:

```
<template>
    <div class="level-item has-text-centered">
        <div>
            <p class="heading">{{ heading }}</p>
            <p class="title">{{ subHeading }}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'StatisticsBannerItem',
    props: {
        heading: {
            required: true
        },
        subHeading: {
            required: true
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

Test source:

```
import { shallow, mount } from '@vue/test-utils';
import StatisticsBannerItem from '../../../src/components/statistics-banner-item.vue';


describe('Statistics Banner', () => {  
    it('renders item with props data correctly', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(StatisticsBannerItem, {
            propsData: {
                heading: 'Test Heading',
                subHeading: 'Test Subheading'
            }
        });
        // assertions
    });
});
```

However, according to the [official documentation](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/en/api/wrapper/props.html), the `propsData` object should be providing the props to the component.

How do I correctly pass props to a component in a test?

Comment: The code you shared is correct, so maybe the problem comes from another test or another component which uses this component.

Comment: I have isolated this single test, nothing else is using it.

Comment: Is it a typo in the real code you're using? like `propsData: { propsData: {}}` or something like that?

Comment: Your code is fine. Just tested it. You have some other problem, somewhere else.

Comment: That is unfortunate, guess I'm stuck then.

Comment: What are your versions? Maybe the problem is there.

Answer (score 6):

The problem was the test output was not as clear as it perhaps should be. The errors were coming from another test (another `it` inside the same file) that was not being passed props - the test output was arranged in a way that made it appear as though the errors were coming from the test in the question.

Comment: That's why a question should include a [mcve]. If it doesn't, we can't help.